# How do I get first element of each array via Linq C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, linq

I'm very new to `Linq` and having a problem with this code:

```
double[] values;
private List<double[]> valueList = new List<double[]>();
void AddNewValues(double d1, double d2, double d3)
{
   values[0] = d1;
   values[1] = d1;
   values[2] = d1;
   valueList.Add(values);
}

void GetAllFirstValues()
{
   var test = valueList.Where(s => s == typeof(double[0]));
}
```

How to get the first item of each array inside the list?

Is that even possible? Is `Linq` here a proper way to do that or is there a more clever solution?

Comment: `var test = valueList.Where(s => s == typeof(double[0])).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Why `typeof(double[0])` and not `s.First()`? Why you use [`typeof`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/typeof) at all? Use `valueList.Select(s => s.First())`

Comment: Aside from the fact `typeof(double[0])` is not valid syntax, the check `s == typeof(double[])` will never be true in the above example. `s` is an double array value, while `typeof(double[])` would return the _Type_. If you want to check if it is a double array you'll need `s.GetType() == typeof(double[])` or with pattern matching `s is double[]`. However, this is unneeded in your code as the List is typed to a double[].

Comment: lots of problems/weirdness with your setup code that should be fixed before anybody tries to answer.  1. you haven't initialized the values array, so  the values[0] = d1, etc. statements will all  throw exceptions.   2.   You are assigning the value of d1 to the array elements all three times,  ignoring d2 and d3 (probably not your intention).     It would probably help you to first add several calls to  AddNewValues() so you can see what's wrong with your AddNewValues() method.

Answer (score 10):

This should be `System.Linq`, you don't need to check for type. It will select first or default if array is empty and return it.

```
IEnumerable<double> d =  l.Select(array => array.FirstOrDefault())
```

or, if you want to filter only non empty arrays:

```
IEnumerable<double> d = l.Where(array => array.Any()).Select(array => array.First());
```

Be aware that array also can be `null`, so you can even filter that out within the `Where` clause.